# fter adding : export const USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME='authenticatedUser to a class in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

after adding : export const  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME='authenticatedUser'

and import API_URL from '../../Constants'; to "class AuthenticationService{"

```
import API_URL from '../../Constants';

export const  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME='authenticatedUser';



class AuthenticationService{



    executeBasicAuthenticationService(username, password){
    //let basicAuthHeader ='Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
    return axios.get(`${API_URL}/basicauth`,
    {headers: {authrization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password)}}); ///thi is not included in the lesson

}
```

and creating a Constants class with following code:

```
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
```

**I get this error.**

```
./src/components/todo/AuthenticationService.js
Attempted import error: '../../Constants' does not contain a default export (imported as 'API_URL')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Context**

```
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
```

The above is not a default export, but you're trying to import it as if it is one here:

```
import API_URL from '../../Constants';
```

---

**Answer**

To import a non-default export from a module you could do something like this instead:

```
import {API_URL} from '../../Constants';
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more info